# What are the numbers lying between $4/5$ and $6/7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the numbers lying between $4/5$ and $6/7$?

I know this is a very basic question but still I am not able to solve this since I am not very good at mathematics.

Comment: There are infinitely many

Comment: Maybe converting the numbers to decimals would make the answer more apparent, but like said above, there are quite a "few" to choose from

Comment: The snarky but perfectly correct answer, is that those numbers would be represented by the interval $(\frac 45, \frac 67)$

Comment: If you could share, in your question, at what level you are studying at, you're more likely to get an answer that best can address your situation.

Comment: E.g., are you learning about the real number-line, have you learned that the the real numbers are uncountably infinite? and that within any interval of two distinct real numbers, there are uncountably infinite real numbers?

Answer (score 2):

First of all we have $4\cdot 7=28<30=5\cdot 6$, so we have $\frac{4}{5}<\frac{6}{7}$.

To see which fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ are between the two numbers , you have $\frac{4}{5}<\frac{a}{b}<\frac{6}{7}$, so assuming that $a$ and $b$ are positive , we must satisfy the two inequalities $4b<5a$ and $7a<6b$ simultaneously, if we multiply the first inequality with $7$ and the second with $5$, we get the double inequality $$28b<35a<30b$$

which is necessary and sufficient

A particular solution can be find faster if we transform the fraction $\frac{4}{5}$ into $\frac{28}{35}$ and the fraction $\frac{6}{7}$ into $\frac{30}{35}$. Then, it is immediately clear that $\frac{29}{35}$ is a number with the desired property.

Comment: I don't quite understand why $28b \lt 35a \lt 30b$ is somehow supposed to be more meaningful than $\frac 4 5 \lt n \lt \frac 6 7$.  Seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question can depend upon the context in which it is being asked.

1. With *no context being given*, the most general answer is, as noted by @Doug M is the entire open interval of real numbers lying between the two numbers, the interval $\left(\dfrac{4}{5},\dfrac{6}{7}\right)$.
2. Since each of the number has the form $\dfrac{n}{n+1}$ if the context is *all numbers of that form*, then the answer is $\dfrac{4}{5}<\dfrac{5}{6}<\dfrac{6}{7}$.
3. Since both numbers are rational numbers, if the context is *rational numbers* then the answer is all numbers of the form $\dfrac{y}{x}$ where the point $(x,y)$ is one of the "solid" points in the shaded region in the following diagram lying between the lines $y=\frac{4}{5}x$ and $y=\frac{6}{7}x$, but not the "hollow" points. Do you see why the "hollow" points are excluded?

[image: rational number satisfying condition]